# Copy paste with line number in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Can you please tell me how can I copy some lines of code in Notepad ++, along with its lines number ?

That is, supposed I have a code.txt opened by notepad ++ like this (numbers are displayed by using Settings --> Preferences --> Editing --> Display line number):

```
1 This is line 1
2 This is line 2 
.
.
n This is line n
```

I want to copy it into a .doc / .odt file so that the line number is included in the result, **NOT** like this:

```
This is line 1
This is line 2 
    .
    .
This is line n
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You should add line number to your document opened in nodepad++. Then you copied to .doc or other files. To realize this, there may be two ways. For both two ways.
**Select your lines in nodepad++**.

**1)** Use **TextFX->TextFX Tools->Insert line numbers.**
[image]

Instead to this, 
**2)** To remove unnecessary leading zeros

2.1)First Left indent
**TextFX->TextFX Edit->Indent text sticky left margin**
[image]

2.2)Add numbers
 **Edit->Column Editors**
in Number to Insert

- Set Intial Number 1
- Increase by 1
- Choose Dec option.

[image]
I hope this will help.

Comment: @swemon +1 for screenshots :)

Comment: On step 2.1, instead of using the plugin TextFX to indent, alternatively you could just Ctrl-A to select all text the press the tab key to indent all. Then go on to step 2.2.

Comment: Step 2.2 is the answer.  The rest of the answer is confusing and unnecessary in my opinion.  Why would someone use an addon when the capability is built directly into the program?  You can use Column editor to insert white space as well as the numbers.

Answer (score 12):

This can be done easily without using any addon if you are not strict towards the format of line no. Your file is

```
1 This is line 1
2 This is line 2 
.
.
n This is line n
```

go to find, put `.*` in `find what` ie regular expression to look everything in a line, then click `find all in current document`. You will get following in search window.

```
Line 1: 1 This is line 1
Line 2: 2 This is line 2 
Line 3: .
Line 4: .
Line 5: n This is line n
```

You can copy the content of search window `[right click in the search window -> select all -> copy]` and paste in another file. Of course line no is not only number but `Line #:`. If it is acceptable then your work is done.

Comment: Really Easy and simple.

Comment: After that you can use multi-cursor (`Alt+Shift+Arrowkey`) technique to remove `Line ` expression from beginning of lines. OR replacing every "Line " with "" if you are sure that your text does't have this expression.

Comment: I tried both yours and swemon's answer. I realized that swemon's method 2 doesn't can be modified to use without a plugin. It's the fastest. `Ctrl-A` then `tab`, then `Alt-C` then Enter. (provided that in step 2.2 you have inserted the numbers before.) This is fastest as there is no mouse required, everything can be done in 1~2 seconds.

Comment: @huggie Is there any way to undo the line number addition?

Answer (score 10):

Step 2.2 is very simple.

Open the file in notepad++

Numbers will be applied to the portion of the file that you select.  for instance  A will apply numbers to the entire file.

Go to menu Edit/Column Editor or use the hot key ALT+C.

The column editor will open as shown above.

Click on the radio button for "Number to Insert".
Start at 1
Increment by 1
Click OK.

You should see line numbers inserted into your file.  Save this as something like myFileWithLineNumbers.js

Comment: Are you referring to step 2.2 in the accepted answer?